# Image from gallery is not displayed on the image button

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

From the App I should be able to add an image from my gallery to the image button, then add Food name, Description and Price and finally click upload.
The image should be uploaded to my firebase storage while Price,Description and Food name should be uploaded to the firebase database

`StorageReference filePath = storageReference.child(uri.getLastPathSegment());` causes an error so the image is not displayed on the image button nor uploaded to firebase storage.

```
public class AddFood extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageButton foodImage;
private static final int GALLREQ=1;
private EditText name,desc,price;
private Uri uri = null;
private StorageReference storageReference = null;
private DatabaseReference mRef;
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_food);

    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ItemName);
    desc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ItemDesc);
    price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ItemPrice);
    storageReference=  FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    mRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Item");

}


public void ImageButtonclicked(View view){
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,GALLREQ);


}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode==GALLREQ&& resultCode==RESULT_OK) {


            uri = data.getData();
            foodImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.FoodImageButton);
            foodImage.setImageURI(uri);

    }


}

public void uploadClicked(View view){
   final String name_text = name.getText().toString().trim();
   final String desc_text = desc.getText().toString().trim();
    String price_text = price.getText().toString().trim();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name_text)&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_text)&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(price_text)){

        StorageReference filePath = storageReference.child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                final Uri downloaduri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                Toast.makeText(AddFood.this,"uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        final  DatabaseReference newPost = mRef.push();
        newPost.child("name").setValue(name_text);
        newPost.child("desc").setValue(desc);
        newPost.child("price").setValue(price_text);


    }

}

}
```

Comment: I can't see where are you calling your `uploadClicked()` method?

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes

Comment: i don't get what you are trying to say

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes The method just checks if name_text, desc_text and price_text are not empty and then uploads them and the Image from gallary, to the database

Comment: I know what the method does, but it looks like it is never used in your code.